# How to open fragment from adapter class without using Intent?

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter

I want to call Fragment from Adapter Class but not able to do so..
So please some method to call the fragment. I have got a method of first calling activity and then switching the fragment is there any other method

Here is the code:

```
public class FanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FanAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{

private Context mContext;
private List<Fan> FanList;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView testTitle;
    public CardView mCardView;


    public MyViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        mCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        testTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fan_name);

    }
}


public FanAdapter(Context mContext, List<Fan> FanList)
{
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.FanList = FanList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fanslist, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Fan album = FanList.get(position);
    holder.testTitle.setText(album.getName());

    holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Slecteditem= String.valueOf(position);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), position);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();


            Fragment fragment = new ProfileDisplay();
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("itemname", Slecteditem);
            args.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_toplayout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Profile"+album.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });



    // loading album cover using Glide library

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return FanList.size();
}
```

}

The editor is not able to resolve getActivity() method in

```
 FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: `FragmentManager fm = mContext.getFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `mContext` to `getFragmentManager();`. Cast the `mContext` to `Activity`.

Something like this.

```
FragmentManager fm = (Activity)mContext.getFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do so would be using a interface to notify the class which calls the adapter.

Something like this:

```
public interface NotifyChange {

    void onItemClicked();
}
```

Then in onItemClicked() do the operation, you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your question, if you a calling the `FanAdapter` class in a fragment, create a `FragmentManager`  inside  `FanClass` List like this

```
private FragmentManager fragment;
public FragmentManager getFragment() {
    return fragment;
}

public void setFragment(FragmentManager fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
```

and also add it to the `Fan` constructor

```
public  Fan(FragmentManager fm){
     this.fragment=fm;
}
```

In your `OnClickListener` body

```
FragmentTransaction ft=fan.get(position).getFragment().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fd);
ft.commit();
```

In Your List you should add `getFragmentManager();`

```
fan.add(new fan(your,own,variables,getFragmentManager()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for replacing fragment from adapter class;

```
  Fragment fragment = new YourFragmentName();
  FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
  ft.commit();

   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString("itemname", Slecteditem);
   args.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
   fragment.setArguments(args);
```